# Docker For Desktop installed in Win 10 with Linux Container is unable to run hello-world image

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have downloaded "Docker for Windows Installer" and run the installer with option "Linux Container" in my Windows 10 machine. The installation went successful. Hyper-v got enabled. Also the virtualization is enabled.

I could successfully run the command docker --version.
But when I am trying to run "docker run hello-world"  I am getting the below error :

> Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
>   C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest:  request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
>   See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

When I went to option switch to Windows container, I could successfully run the docker image.
But again when I switch back to Linux Container I am facing the same issue.

I have checked with DNS 8.8.8.8 in the settings, also tried restarting docker, but no help till now.

Also When I switch to Windows Container and try to run a Dockerfile I get the below error :

> Sending build context to Docker daemon  113.2kB
>   Step 1/4 : FROM java:8
>   8: Pulling from library/java
>   image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the latest version, resolved my issue. I am able to run containers on Linux and Windows both. hello-world image is running.

I have taken the following steps :

```
 1. Uninstall Docker for Desktop.
 2. Remove docker folder and files from AppData : Local and Roaming.
 3. Remove docker folder from Program data
 4. Remoce .docker inside <C:\Users\UserName\> folder.
 5. Remove temp files
 6. Download latest version (my version :  2.3.0.2)
 7. Install Docker
 8. Enable Kubernetes.
```

I can now build docker images and run the containers,use kubernetes, orchestration everything is running fine. But I am using Linux containers. As I dont want windows containers.